# Applying "box-sizing: border-box" reset will break layout when image height is in percentage

Tags: html, css

I have a simple header with logo inside it. This is working until I apply `box-sizing: border-box` reset.

Here is working header:

```css
.header-container {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.app-logo {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.app-logo img {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="app-logo">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Flag_of_Montenegro_%281993-2004%29.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is broken one:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit
}

.header-container {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.app-logo {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.app-logo img {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="app-logo">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Flag_of_Montenegro_%281993-2004%29.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Why is image inside `.app-logo` not displayed when `box-sizing` is applied?**

I tried to change height `.app-logo img {height: 30px;}` to pixels, then the image is visible again, but I would prefer to have it to `100%` so that logo's height will adjust to it's container.

Comment: becausse all the padding is inside the height so nothing for the image. you have 30px height and 2*15px padding

Comment: @Manjuboyz I want to add box-sizing reset into my styles, so all elements use `box-sizing: border-box` instead of default `content-box`.

Comment: @Temani Afif, of course, that make sense. Thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see, `box-sizing: border-box` make elements to count padding like a part of the size. So in

```
.app-logo {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
```

The top and bottom paddings are 15px. 15+15 = 30, so the height of this element is. And there is nothing left for the content.

Here, replaced `padding: 15px 20px;` in `.header-container`

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit
}

.header-container {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.app-logo {
  height: 30px;  
}

.app-logo img {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="app-logo">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Flag_of_Montenegro_%281993-2004%29.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the padding on the parent left no space for the image, see the snippet below.

height: 100% now works

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit
}

.header-container {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.app-logo {
  height: 30px;
  /*padding: 15px 20px; this bit of padding takes all the space*/ 
}

.app-logo img {
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="app-logo">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Flag_of_Montenegro_%281993-2004%29.png">
  </div>
</div>
```